# Create a Custom Post Types posts with open latest one

Tags: php, wordpress

I am making a accordion on faq page and When i open faq page I would like it to open most recent post, I have made a custom post type for it and i am not using any plugin for accordion i have just copied code from *dreamweaver* for it.
I'm using code below :-

```
<?php $recentPosts = new WP_Query(array('showposts' => 1, 'post_type' => 'FAQ'));
while( $recentPosts->have_posts() ) : 
    $recentPosts->the_post(); ?>

    <div id="Accordion1" class="Accordion" tabindex="0">
          <div class="AccordionPanel">
             <div class="AccordionPanelTab">
             <?php the_title(); ?>
             </div>
             <div class="AccordionPanelContent"> <?php the_content(); ?> </div> 
          </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>   

     </div>
```

**Function.php**

```
add_action('init', 'cptui_register_my_cpt_faq');
function cptui_register_my_cpt_faq() {
register_post_type('faq', array(
'label' => 'FAQ',
'description' => '',
'public' => true,
'show_ui' => true,
'show_in_menu' => true,
'capability_type' => 'post',
'map_meta_cap' => true,
'hierarchical' => false,
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'faq', 'with_front' => true),
'query_var' => true,
'supports' => array('title','editor','excerpt','trackbacks','custom-fields','comments','revisions','thumbnail','author','page-attributes','post-formats'),
'labels' => array (
  'name' => 'FAQ',
  'singular_name' => '',
  'menu_name' => 'FAQ',
  'add_new' => 'Add FAQ',
  'add_new_item' => 'Add New FAQ',
  'edit' => 'Edit',
  'edit_item' => 'Edit FAQ',
  'new_item' => 'New FAQ',
  'view' => 'View FAQ',
  'view_item' => 'View FAQ',
  'search_items' => 'Search FAQ',
  'not_found' => 'No FAQ Found',
  'not_found_in_trash' => 'No FAQ Found in Trash',
  'parent' => 'Parent FAQ',
)
) ); }
```

It was working when i was using it hard coded like this:-

```
<div id="Accordion1" class="Accordion" tabindex="0">
          <div class="AccordionPanel">
             <div class="AccordionPanelTab">
             title
             </div>
             <div class="AccordionPanelContent">content  </div> 
         </div>



          <div class="AccordionPanel">
             <div class="AccordionPanelTab">
             title
             </div>
             <div class="AccordionPanelContent">content </div> 
         </div>
   </div>
```

How can I change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was not a big deal i have just put out of `accordion` main `div` from `loop` and its done easily

```
<div id="Accordion1" class="Accordion" tabindex="0">   
      <?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'FAQ' );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>    
          <div class="AccordionPanel">
             <div class="AccordionPanelTab">
             <?php the_title(); ?>
             </div>
             <div class="AccordionPanelContent"> <?php the_content(); ?> </div> 
         </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>            
   </div>  <!--Accordion1-->
```

Comment: Great. As I saw the static version found the solution. Have great day. Mark the question as resolved. So others can use it.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this code alone,

```
<div id="Accordion1" class="Accordion" tabindex="0">
<?php $recentPosts = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_type' => 'faq'));
while( $recentPosts->have_posts() ) : 
    $recentPosts->the_post(); ?>
      <div class="AccordionPanel">
         <div class="AccordionPanelTab">
            <?php the_title(); ?>
         </div>
         <div class="AccordionPanelContent"> <?php the_content(); ?> </div> 
      </div>
<?php endwhile; ?> 
</div>
```

Put this in the template file. this will work.
The showposts is older one.. So try with posts_per_page..

Comment: Can you show me the working html of the accordion..? So I can fix it.

Comment: No.. I mean, there me be some JS files which would be used for the accordion. So try to include those files too and check.

Comment: [You can see here css](http://myluckybottle.fr/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/css/SpryAccordion.css)
[You can see here js file](http://myluckybottle.fr/wp-content/themes/twentythirteen/js/SpryAccordion.js)

Comment: Okay. Can you revert back the code to list recent posts and put the static code when accordion was working.? Because there may be some div or id may be missing when we populate it dynamically. Please revert and let me know.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Just used the main div outside the loop. try it.